# Blank App Interface, Unresponsive since switch to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, gradle, android-studio

My app was working well when built with Eclipse. Last Night, I switched my app over to Android Studio and actually got it to compile and run. I noticed upon reentering the app later that night, the whole app went blank except for the status bar like shown below. Perhaps someone can recommend a remedy for this? I haven't changed any of my core code.

Here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Here is the gradle for my project:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':AndroidBootstrap')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile project(':android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }



    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

Here is a logcat that might help:

```
12-14 12:28:28.613    8680-8743/com.shamu11.madlibsportablepro D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty    regions requested: true
12-14 12:28:28.622    8680-8680/com.shamu11.madlibsportablepro D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
12-14 12:28:28.710    8680-8743/com.shamu11.madlibsportablepro I/Adreno-EGL﹕  <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/02/14, c40da3f, Ifda814c646
12-14 12:28:28.711    8680-8743/com.shamu11.madlibsportablepro I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL,  version 1.4
12-14 12:28:28.725    8680-8743/com.shamu11.madlibsportablepro D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-14 12:29:29.647    8680-8743/com.shamu11.madlibsportablepro I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/02/14, c40da3f, Ifda814c646
12-14 12:29:29.647    8680-8743/com.shamu11.madlibsportablepro I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

Comment: It's impossible to guess what the problem is without knowing what your app does.

Comment: app is a simple madlibs app, the key thing to know is that this is the view I get when first entering the app, when a data wipe of the app will repopulate my layout correctly @Egor

Comment: Maybe something to do with the position of your `AndroidManifest.xml`. You need to debug your code and add `Log`s to understand what is and isn't running

Comment: well logcat has been mostly unhelpful because it thinks the app is running normally. I tried running in eclipse and didn't get this problem upon swiping the app away and reentering it. @Blundell

Answer (score 0):

So someone on Reddit thought it was a problem with the newest Google play services. Turns out he was correct! I downgraded to Google play services 6.1 to fix this problem. Hopefully Google notices this problem and updates accordingly.

Comment: you could have worked this out yourself with logcat statements, software engineering is not magic

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem of unresponsive application after upgrading play services.
Noticed that the application hangs on the creation of the google analytics object

Downgrading play services to 6.1 solved the problem (as shamu11 advised)